# "otherwise", "usage of comma"

Tags: commas

"That weather report caused the widely respected scientist to acquire a certain reputation among his colleagues as a bit unstable, an otherwise estimable fellow whose hard work may have pushed him over the edge. "  --- From an ACT reading.

First of all, I think that these two sentences are two independent sentences, so they should be divided by a period, rather than a comma.
Besides, I am uncertain about the meaning of "otherwise". Does that mean "other"?
Last, what does "push one over the edge" mean?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: In my opinion the sentence is fine as it is, and changing that comma to a period would be incorrect: the resulting second sentence would not make sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn, these are two complete sentences, but they are linked by a linking word. So why can they be divided by a comma?

Comment: *Otherwise* as used in that sentence is not a linking word. The phrase after the comma does not make sense on its own, it would need to be rephrased to stand independently.

Comment: @CharlieWang If you changed the comma to a period, the (now) second "sentence" would be a noun phrase only. It would be a sentence fragment instead of a complete sentence.